# Better way to access data from multple tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, lumen

I am using Laravel 5.4. i have 15 tables which has registerId in all tables

i have two situation where

1.i need to retrieve all data from all tables

2.another situation is based on registerId

i have tried using follwoing method

```
$data=[];
$data['table1']=ModelName::get();
$data['table2']=ModelName::get();
$data['table3']=ModelName::get();
```

like this continue
another way i did is using `left join` based on registration id

I felt like it will be huge performance issue later when the rows increases

Any one suggest me best method so performance will be better

Answer (score 1):

You could use pagination to limit the number of results per table.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination

I would personally use ajax to request table data so the page load is fast and then populate each table independently. DataTables is a library I frequently use.

https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/

Making 15 `SELECT *...` each time a request comes in is going to certainly be a performance issue, especially if you start having multiple concurrent users.

Comment: @btn.i have situation where i need to insert to all taables also.thanks

Comment: Check the datatables API for form submission. Example here: https://datatables.net/examples/api/form.html